# How to get input command from keyboard on client/server in C while server is also listening for other requests?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, select, client-server

I am writing a client server program in C. The problem:
while server is listening and accepting new connections, it is also storing the IP's it is connected to. Now if we enter a command say LIST in the server program window which is still running, then it should display the list of IP's it is connected to ?
I am using the Select() function for each client.

In short, how to accept input from keyboard while answering the incoming connections?

Answer (score 2):

Just include the file descriptor for standard input (`STDIN_FILENO`, aka 0) in the set of file descriptors passed into `select(2)`.  Then, if input is available for reading on that, you read from it and process the command; otherwise, process the sockets as usual.

Alternatively, you could run a separate thread to handle user input, but given that you already have the `select` call in place, it's probably easier to continue using that.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check out D.J. Bernstein's tcpserver (see http://cr.yp.to/ucspi-tcp/tcpserver.html). Basically, you can simply run your program under tcpserver, and tcpserver will handle everything as far as setting up the sockets, listing for incoming connections on whatever port you are using, etc. When an incoming connection arrives on the port that you specify, tcpserver will spawn an instance of your program and pipe incoming info from the client to your program's STDIN, and pipe outgoing info from your program's STDOUT back to the client. This way, you can concentrate on your program's core logic (and simply read/write to stdout/stdin), and let tcpserver handle all of the heavy lifting as far as the sockets, etc., and you can accept multiple simultaneous incoming connections this way.

As far as knowing the client ip's that are currently connected - this can be done at the command line by using netstat while the server is running.